# Replace NA with value within group for subset

Tags: r, performance, loops, data.table, subset

I need to replace missing values in all columns of a data frame within ID and time point for a subgroup that have data from several sources. If it is not too complicated, it would be best to prioritize data from source B (e.g., in case of id 2 for variable Y in the data below).

Using the code below, it currently works (without prioritizing) for one column at the time, but since its a large data frame with millions of rows, it needs to be automated further. Also, I would like to keep it within the data.table framework if possible. Any advice?

```
# Data
id  time  X  Y   Source
1   2005  67 NA  A
1   2005  NA 1.1 B
1   2005  NA 1.1 B
2   2003  85 NA  B
2   2003  NA 0.4 A
2   2003  85 0.5 B

# Desired output
id  time  X  Y   Source
1   2005  67 1.1 A
1   2005  67 1.1 B
1   2005  67 1.1 B
2   2003  85 0.5 B
2   2003  85 0.4 A
2   2003  85 0.5 B

# Find duplicates
dup <- (duplicated(dat[,c('id','time')])|duplicated(dat[,c('id','time')], fromLast=TRUE))

# Replace NA in column X
library(data.table)
dat[dup & is.na(X), X := dat[!is.na(X)][.SD, on=.(id,time), mult="last", X]]

### Solution based on locf and an internal data.table loop (still slower than tidyverse)

    library(data.table)
    library(zoo)

    cols <- colnames(dat)[c(-1,-2)]
    dat <- dat[order(id,time,Source)] # this combined with na.locf0(fromLast=T) takes care of the priority.
    dup <- (duplicated(dat[,c('id','time')])|duplicated(dat[,c('id','time')], fromLast=TRUE))

    t1 <- Sys.time() 
      dat=rbind(
        dat[!dup],
        dat[dup, lapply(.SD, na.locf0,fromLast = TRUE), by=c('id','time'), .SDcols = cols][
            ,lapply(.SD, na.locf0), by=c('id','time'), .SDcols = cols]
      )
    t2 <- Sys.time()
    t2-t1
```

Comment: I'm a bit confused could you show the desired output?

Comment: Sorry about that, added now.

Answer (score 0):

```
library(tidyverse)
library(data.table)

Data <- data.table(id = c(1,1,1,2,2,2), time = c(2005, 2005, 2005, 2003, 2003, 2003), X = c(67, NA, NA, 85, NA, 85),
                       Y = c(NA, 1.1, 1.1, NA, 0.4, 0.5), Source = c("A", "B", "B", "B", "A", "B"))

Data <- Data %>% 
  group_by(id, Source) %>% 
  fill(time, X, Y) %>%
  fill(time, X, Y, .direction = "up")

Data <- Data %>% 
  group_by(id) %>% 
  fill(time, X, Y) %>%
  fill(time, X, Y, .direction = "up")
```

I am not sure if you mean that source "B" is always preferred or if it is only preferred when the source of the sample is also "B" (and thus the preferred source would be "A" if that sample's source was "A"). This code solves the issue for the latter scenario. 
It requires tidyverse.

Comment: Please include all `library` lines as this does not appear to be `data.table`. OP requested: *I would like to keep it within the data.table framework if possible*.

Comment: Thank you for this! I have been using a similar solution, but it is getting too slow as my dataset is expanding. The remaining data management is also conducted in the data.table framework, so bringing it all there would be great. I think the solution has something to do with .SDcols and (cols) in it, but haven't quite figured it out.

Answer (score 0):

Here are 3 options:

1) Using a `for` loop with `get`:

```
for (x in updcols) {
    DT0[dup & is.na(get(x)), (x) := DT0[!is.na(get(x))][
        .SD, on=.(id,time), mult="last", get(x)]]   
}
DT0
```

2) Using `for` loop with non-standard evaluation:

```
nsef <- function(dat, coln) {
    eval(substitute(
        dat[dup & is.na(V), V := dat[!is.na(V)][.SD, on=.(id,time), mult="last", V]],
        list(V=as.name(coln))
    ))
}
for (x in updcols) {
    nsef(DT1, x)
}
DT1
```

3) Extract the last non-NA values and perform a join and then update by reference:

```
lu <- DT2[, lapply(.SD, function(x) last(x[!is.na(x)])), bycols, .SDcols=updcols]
DT2[(dup), (updcols) := 
    lu[.SD, on=bycols, Map(function(x, y) fcoalesce(x, y), 
        mget(paste0("i.", updcols)), mget(updcols))]
]
DT2
```

You can also use `fifelse` (version >= 1.12.4) instead of `fcoalesce` (i.e. `fcoalesce(X, Y) == fifelse(is.na(X), Y, X)`).

I think timing will depend on the characteristics of your actual dataset.

output:

```
   id time  X   Y Source
1:  1 2005 67 1.1      A
2:  1 2005 67 1.1      B
3:  1 2005 67 1.1      B
4:  2 2003 85 0.5      B
5:  2 2003 85 0.4      A
6:  2 2003 85 0.5      B
```

data:

```
library(data.table) #data.table_1.12.6
DT <- fread("id  time  X  Y   Source
1   2005  67 NA  A
1   2005  NA 1.1 B
1   2005  NA 1.1 B
2   2003  85 NA  B
2   2003  NA 0.4 A
2   2003  85 0.5 B")
DT0 <- copy(DT)
DT1 <- copy(DT)
DT2 <- copy(DT)
bycols <- c('id','time')
updcols <- c("X", "Y")
dup <- duplicated(DT, by=bycols) | duplicated(DT, by=bycols, fromLast=TRUE)
```

Comment: Thank you for this effort! Unfortunately, these solutions were too slow for my dataset (which contains a mix of variable types), but they helped me come to the solution above.